# Load YAML files in structured folders with OmegaConf

Tags: python, yaml, omegaconf

```
configs
|_________ experiment
|         |--------- test.yaml
|--------- default.yaml
```

`default.yaml` has some configuration parameters and then

```
experiment: test.yaml
```

`test.yaml` defines more parameters, such as `learning_rate: 0.1`.
I would like to load them recursively with `OmegaConf`. If I do

```py
from omegaconf import DictConfig, OmegaConf
conf = OmegaConf.load("configs/default.yaml")
```

It doesn't work because `conf` has key `experiment` with value `test`, rather than key `learning_rate` with value `0.1`.
It is possible to read YAML files recursively?

Comment: The YAML specification has no such functionality, but the appropriate way to implement it is to register some tag (e.g. `!Include`) that interpreters the following scalar as a filename, loads the data structure in that file (recursively) and replaces the tagged scalar node with that data structure. That way you can replace individual mapping values (and keys), as well as sequence items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OmegaConf is a low level library. It does not support higher level functionality like what you seems to be asking for.
If you want to compose configs from multiple files/sources into a single object, I recommend that you use Hydra (`@hydra.main()` or the [Compose API](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/compose_api/)).

Comment: I am already using Hydra but I am having trouble using it with the `submitit` plugin, so I am trying to make my own script where I use `submitit` to call my main with a sweep over the args. The args must be passed as a `DictConfig`, and here is where I got stuck. I am now using `compose` to read them and it works. Thanks!